# BubbleLayout is not working in service

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-inflater

This is my code but it's not working in a service. The layout is not inflating.

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

BubbleLayout bubbleView = (BubbleLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bubble_layout, null);
```

Comment: What do you mean by **Not working** ?, please add some details

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Above code, 'BubbleLayout' is Layout,Just use view to store your inflate          Example:View mView=llayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bubble_layout, null);

Comment: then how to destroy that layout like bubble layout

Comment: layout is not inflating

Comment: Why are you inflating your layout in Service class??

Comment: because i want to create bubble on get push notification

Comment: Then you can use broad cast receiver and when you get message just inflate layout in `onReceive()` method.

Comment: i am using GCMPushReceiverService and inflating layout in onMessageRecive()

Comment: So in that method you can get context for that service class. Did u use that ? Can you share some snippet for that class ? @DharaPatel

Comment: @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) { sendNotification(message); }    There is no getContext method

Comment: Use `LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)` or `LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(GCMPushReceiverService.this)` @DharaPatel Did u check this ?

Comment: @Piyush no it is not working

Comment: @DharaPatel You can use _getApplicationContext()_ and also _GCMPushReceiverService.this_ will give the context of that class. Because if it is extends with `IntentService` then it is itself as a `Context`. So you can use as a `Context context = this;` too

Comment: my class is extend from GcmListenerService

Comment: it is working in activity properly but not working in service

Comment: @DharaPatel Are you sure that you getting `getBaseContext` null ? Did u debug it or print in Log ?

Comment: i have already tried with getBaseContext but it also not working

Comment: Use this.  `if(getBaseContext() instanceof YourActivity){
            YourActivity yourActivity = (YourActivity)getBaseContext();
        }` and then use `yourActivity ` as a context. @DharaPatel

Comment: @DharaPatel Checked??

Comment: @Piyush not working

Comment: @DharaPatel I think the problem is because of other thing not with context